# Which is the accessory power fuse for a Honda City 2018

Tags: honda, fuse-panel

I am unable to decipher which fuse is which in my Honda City 2018 going by the markings on the fuse box and the owner's manual.

Which is the fuse for the 12V power outlet?

[image]

I expected to find the fuses here, but there are none to be seen, only a mini glove-box:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the fuse diagram for the underhood fuse box. You need the one which is in the cabin. Here's the one which is in the cabin:

[image]

The fuses are located behind the driver's pocket in the picture posted, but the pocket is not removable. You have to stick your head under it to see the fuses. 
NOTE: They are upside-down with respect to each other:

[image]

There is a group of four yellow 20 A fuses from 39 - 42. 40, 41 & 42 are for the power windows, and 39 is the one you want for the accessory power.

Answer (score 1):

Paulster2 is correct that you’re looking at the wrong panel diagram.

That said [here’s a PDF from Honda](http://techinfo.honda.com/rjanisis/pubs/OM/TK0707/TK0707O00397A.PDF) that lists the fuse as #28 for the accessory (console compartment). I’m also not sure of the year, or model because of the way that the site is configured, so I recommend you do the following:

Basically what you need to do is look for the section in your manual that shows the interior fuse panel and see what that says. Alternatively, if you open the panel, there is usually a diagram on the inside of the lid that will also list the data you need.